# cron task wouldn't work, why?

Tags: shell, cron

I want to write a cron task to record the ntpdate synchronization info into the system log, but there's no such info printed in the /var/log/messages after this cron task is done, where did I do wrong?

The followings are what my crontab looks like.

```
*/1 * * * * ntpdate 192.168.100.97 | logger -t "NTP"
*/1 * * * * echo "log test" | logger -t "TEST"
*/1 * * * * whoami | logger -t "WHO"
```

When I do tailf /var/log/messages and wait some time I only got the following lines, the NTP lines are missing.

```
Oct 29 15:22:01 localhost TEST: log test
Oct 29 15:22:01 localhost WHO: root
Oct 29 15:23:01 localhost TEST: log test
Oct 29 15:23:01 localhost WHO: root
Oct 29 15:24:01 localhost TEST: log test
Oct 29 15:24:01 localhost WHO: root
Oct 29 15:25:01 localhost TEST: log test
Oct 29 15:25:01 localhost WHO: root
Oct 29 15:26:01 localhost TEST: log test
Oct 29 15:26:01 localhost WHO: root
```

But when I do the *ntpdate 192.168.100.97 | logger -t "NTP"* in the command line, I could see there's message *Oct 29 15:28:39 localhost NTP: 29 Oct 15:28:39 ntpdate[11101]: adjust time server 192.168.100.97 offset 0.000043 sec* print out in the system log. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Have you tried giving the complete path to `ntpdate` (possibly `/usr/sbin/ntpdate`)? I'm never sure how much is in the environment of cronjobs.

Comment: Ooh, that's where am I missing! thanks man, it works all right now.  :)